# Pop_OS! 19.10 to 20.03 Upgrade Fail?

Tags: boot, fstab

Clicking `Download` shows these error
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aazzB.png).
Tried `sudo findmnt --verify`, it shows

```
findmnt: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 12 -- ignored

1 parse error, 0 errors, 0 warnings
```

this is my `fstab` file data, line 12 is the last line of the fstab.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
PARTUUID=b2c0a10c-e96c-433e-b8ac-7b715fa2a7f5 /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 0
PARTUUID=fd61081f-a9ad-43ca-88a4-4a0e81f30ab3 /recovery vfat umask=0077 0 0
UUID=65ebd001-d3c2-4c68-8747-36096f6e2346 / ext4 noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
/dev/mapper/cryptswap none swap defaults 0 0
LABEL=New Volume /mnt/New Volume auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

N.B. `New Volume` is my old hard drive, `NTFS` format which I reinstalled replacing my Old `DVD Drive`, Boot drive is an `SSD`.
I am new to Linux and not sure what to do next, any help?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue, my Volume name had space in the middle. I changed the name into a single word. Unmounted the volume. Then removed the `New Volume` directory from the `/mnt/` directory. In the `fstab` file changed accordingly. This time instead of `LABEL` i used `UUID` which I retrieved using `sudo blkid`. at the end, `fstab` files last line looked like this

```
UUID=<UUID-of-the-partition> /mnt/Old auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

`sudo findmnt --verify` didn't show any error. and could download and upgrade `pop_os!` to `20.03`.